# Django - Error received when anonymous user submits form

Tags: python, django

In one of my views I have a form where when a user logs in and submits the form, it works fine.

However, when an anonymous user submits the form I get the following error:

```
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x1052fd3a0>>": "User_Inquiries.user" must be a "CustomUser" instance.
```

This form needs to be submitted whether a user is anonymous or logged in.
What do I need to do in order to resolve this issue?

Code below.

Any help is gladly appreciated. Thanks!

views.py

```
def account_view_contact(request):
    form = ContactUsForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,)
    user_profile = User_Inquiries.objects.all()
    user_profile = User_Info.objects.all()
    user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":  # checking if request is POST or Not
        # if its a post request, then its checking if the form is valid or not
        if form.is_valid():
            contact_instance = form.save(commit=False)  # "this will return the 'Listing' instance"
            contact_instance.user = user # assign 'user' instance
            contact_instance.save() # calling 'save()' method of model
            return redirect("home")         
    
    context = {
         'form': form, 'user_profile': user_profile
    }

    return render(request, 'contact.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class User_Inquiries(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_submitted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "User Inquiries"
        
    @property
    def user_message(self):
        return truncatechars(self.message, 30)
```

Comment: To what should the `.user` attribute point if the user is not logged in?

Comment: Try: ``null=True`` and ``blank=True`` for ``user``. The issue in the ``user`` relationship (``ForeignKey``).

Comment: @16350436 no luck. when I tried that I get the same error.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem if no user is logged I thought it would create an Anonymous User object. Shouldn't that be happening?

Comment: @spidey677: the same `AnonymousUser` object is used for all requests without a user logged in. Furthermore `AnonymousUser` has no database table, hence you can not link to an `AnonymousUser` in the database: your `ForeignKey` only refers to `User` objects.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ohhh i see. So what should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Create a Django form (``InquiriesForm``), make the user field in the form a ``CharField``, and then ``InquiriesForm(initial={"user":request.user})`` in your ``views.py``.

Comment: @16350436 I get the same error... I think it's something to do with Willem was saying.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is :

**First**, add a user field with `null=True`

```
class User_Inquiries(models.Model):
    # ....
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # ...
```

**Second**, in your view, you need to provide the `user` field only if the user is authenticated. Because `AnonymousUser` can be saved in the database.

```
def account_view_contact(request):
    user_profile = User_Info.objects.all()
    
    # If it's a post request
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ContactUsForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None,)
        if form.is_valid():
            if request.user is authenticated:
                # Only authenticated user can be assigned
                contact_instance = form.save(commit=False)
                contact_instance.user = request.user
                contact_instance.save()
                return redirect("home")
            else:
                # Save the form without user because no user is logged in
                form.save()
    
    # Handle no POST request
    else:
        form = ContactUsForm()
        context = {
            'form': form, 'user_profile': user_profile
        }
        
        return render(request, 'contact.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

the User_Inquiries model user should be blank = True and null = True. In the view check if the user is logged in before setting the contact_instance.user to user.

models.py

```
class User_Inquiries(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def account_view_contact(request):
    form = ContactUsForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,)
    user_profile = User_Inquiries.objects.all()
    user_profile = User_Info.objects.all()
    # check if the user is authenticated
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user

    if request.method == "POST":  # checking if request is POST or Not
        # if its a post request, then its checking if the form is valid or not
       if form.is_valid():
            contact_instance = form.save(commit=False)  # "this will return the 'Listing' instance"
            contact_instance.user = user # assign 'user' instance
            contact_instance.save() # calling 'save()' method of model
            return redirect("home")         

    context = {
         'form': form, 'user_profile': user_profile
    }

    return render(request, 'contact.html', context)
```

[check if user is authenticated in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests)

[set null and blank = True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solutions and it worked. I also used CreateView to figure this out and it worked flawlessly. Code below:

```
class account_view_contact(CreateView):
    model = User_Inquiries
    form_class = ContactUsForm
    template_name = "contact.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("home")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            self.object.created_by = self.request.user
            self.object.save()
        else:     
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Thanks Everyone!